# how to pass an array value to system command in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to delete the users in the array from the group but the error says its a syntax error . My array is correct I have printed and checked it . I have even checked the command
 ***system 'NET LOCALGROUP Administrators username /DELETE'*** 
  in the command prompt it works fine . How do I pass the username as a variable to this command .

```
for i in 0..z.length-1

system 'NET LOCALGROUP Administrators z[i] /DELETE'
puts z[i]


end
```

Comment: `system "NET LOCALGROUP Administrators #{z[i]} /DELETE"` note double quotes for string interpolation.

Comment: Furthermore, you should use `for username in z` or - more idiomatic - `z.each do |username|` (you then need to replace `z[i]` with `username`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't want to delete "z[i]" you want to delete the username stored in `z[i]`.  You can do that by interpolating `z[i]` (surround it with `#{}` within a double-quoted string)

```
for i in 0..z.length-1
  system "NET LOCALGROUP Administrators #{z[i]} /DELETE"
  puts z[i]
end
```

Secondly it would be much more readable to use `each` so that you don't have that tortuous index loop.

```
z.each do |user|
  system "NET LOCALGROUP Administrators #{user} /DELETE"
  puts user
end
```

If you do want to use a for loop, note that `0..z.length-1` can be better fomulated using the three-dot syntax  `0...z.length`

Comment: thank you it worked with  #{}.  now im trying to convert this into a chef recipe using batch resource . can you help me with that ?

Comment: To make it easier for others to search for answers to questions, it's better to formulate a follow up question as a new question and post it as so.